# JavaScript dynamic object scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, scope

Is it possible to use created objects in another scope?

```
var iZ = 0;
var pcs = {};
function Pc(_name, _os) //Constructor 
{            
   this.name = _name; // Pc Name
   this.os = _os;    //Pc Os
   this.ausgabe = function()  
   {
   //Do something
   }; iZ++;
}
//Creating a new object 
document.getElementById("pc_create").addEventListener("click", function()
{   
      pcs['pc' + iZ] = new Pc('Pc '+ iZ , os);
      pcs['pc' + iZ].ausgabe();    
});
//Using object in another scope
document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function()
{
      pcs['pc' + iZ].name = "test"; // Doesnt work 
});
```

Is there another way to use solve this ?

Comment: seeing iZ being incremented and referenced inside of onclick makes me wonder if that is really the issue.

Comment: Hey you changed your code entirely! o_0

Answer (score 4):

Use,

```
this.name = _name;
```

Instead of,

```
var name = _name;
```

If you don't assign the `name` to the current object, then that will become `local variable` to that constructor. This is applicable for `os` also.

Also the main error is, whenever you are creating an `instance` you are updating one `variable` by increment its `count`. So if you have created 2 instances, then your 2 objects will be stored like `'pc0'` and `'pc1'` respectively. But the count `iZ` will be `2`. Now if you access `'pc2'` at that time, it will not be fetched, since it was not created. So you could fix it by rewriting your code like below,

```
 pcs['pc' + (iZ-1)].name = "test";
```

Comment: Also point out that `}); iZ++` is wrong since there is an extra brace there.

Comment: @gurvinder372 That was a typo from OP. Just check his question now. Looks like he corrected it by himself.

Answer (score 0):

This works now:

```
document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function()
{
      pcs['pc' + iZ].name = "test"; // Now work 
});
```

Comment: If you decrement it, then while creating new instances, the already existing instances will be replaced.